# How to enforce strong type enforcement in Gson?

Tags: json, kotlin, gson

I am using Gson to parse JSON. What surprised me is that if I have a field of type `String` in my POJO class and I have a `number` in JSON it's parsed correctly without throwing an exception. Similarly the other way - I wrote this test to illustrate:

```
    data class Parsed(
        val testString: String,
        val testNumber: Int,
    )

    @Test
    fun `test gson type parsing`() {
        val gson = Gson()

        val json = "{ \"testString\" : 1, \"testNumber\" : \"1\"}"

        val parsed = gson.fromJson(json, Parsed::class.java)

        assertThat(parsed.testString).isEqualTo("1") // passes
        assertThat(parsed.testNumber).isEqualTo(1) // passes
        // expected an exception because number is parsed into a string field and string is parsed into number
    }
```

Is there any way to change this behavior? (Only found `setLenient()` on `GsonBuilder` but it's not related to this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can turn of type coercion in gson. Your best bet would probably be to write a custom deserializer that prevents this.

That being said, contemplate not using gson in kotlin code as it completely circumvents the null safety of the language. You are better of using a serialization framework that is kotlin aware, such as jackson (with kotlin plugin) or kotlinx-serialization.

Aditionally it seems like jackson allows to turn this specific type coercion off, using this flag: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/MapperFeature.html#ALLOW_COERCION_OF_SCALARS

Kotlinx-serialization seems to not have such an option: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/issues/1042

Comment: Yea that was my idea too. Checked out kotlin serialization and jackson. The kotlin one can't be configured much, jackson has the most advanced type coercion configuration but still I couldn't prevent parsing a json number into string. Still not understand why type coercion would be implemented by default and not as opt-in in a statically typed language. Ended up with writing custom Gson type adapters based on the code of the default ones.

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) the following options:

- Subclass [`JsonReader`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/stream/JsonReader.html) and override its number reading methods (such as `nextInt()`) and `nextString()` to first call `peek()` and verify that the JSON data has the correct type.

  Disadvantages:

  - In theory future Gson versions could add more number reading methods to `JsonReader`
  - There might be type adapters for which it is acceptable to perform this conversion between numbers and strings; however by subclassing `JsonReader` you would break these adapters because your subclass cannot tell the adapters apart
  - Has no effect if a type adapter first deserializes the JSON data as `JsonElement` (and possibly performs modifications or checks on it) and then deserializes that as desired type
- Implement a custom [`TypeAdapterFactory`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html) which wraps adapters for `String` and `Number` and subclasses to first call `JsonReader.peek()` to make sure the JSON data has the correct type

  Disadvantages:

  - It would have to cover all cases where you don't want this type conversion; for example you might also want to cover the built-in `StringBuilder` adapter

Since you are concerned with strict validation, it might be good to point out that Gson by default performs lenient parsing (see [Troubleshooting Guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/Troubleshooting.md#default-lenient)), and even in its 'strict mode' it slightly deviates from the JSON specification, see [this issue](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/2295).